# Is there a structure that can be easily used for MVC JSon?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the example of anonymous object used for ajax result:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});
}
```

This is simple enough, however is there something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  var result = new ????
  result["foo"] = "bar";

  // Do some other stuff
  ...

  result["john"] = "doe";

  // Do some other stuff
  ...

  return Json(result);
}
```

I wish to avoid to create custom class for result, I would prefer something like shown above.

Comment: What's wrong with using an anonymous type?  Maybe you can use a `dynamic` instead?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I would imagine an ExpandoObject would probably work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Comment: The first example in your post is much more readable than the second. My 2 cents...

Comment: @chiccodoro Sometimes you want/need to be able to build up your object as you go through the method, populating it based on whatever logic is going on, and then sending it out as JSON at the end. An anonymous type doesn't lend itself well to that sort of usage.

Comment: @anaximander, Yes that is exactly the point and reason why I asked the question. I will try your answer shortly.

Comment: @anaximander: I have a strong bias towards separating concerns - in this case the concern of gathering or calculating values based on some underlying logic and the concern of stitching the results together as a JSON.

Comment: @chiccodoro I'm all for separating concerns, but if you're preparing a set of things to send, you might as well initialise that collection at the start of your method and populate it as you go. The alternative is to put all the things that you want in the collection into temporary variables, and then shove them all into an anonymous object at the end. Aside from this being a mostly-pointless use of more memory, if your response has certain fields only in certain situations, the part where you shove them into that object will need more logic for that, making your method larger and more complex.

Comment: @chiccodoro: Dude, there is nothing special about populating DTO on the go, there is no need to "separate" concerns and make code complex and less readable.
I can see that anaximander has more experience and common sense, his approaches are perfectly practical and simple - everything he said was like reading my mind.

Comment: @anaximander: I agree. Maybe my comment sounded a bit undifferentiated, although it was not meant to be. I guess that the `// Do some other stuff` comments in the question made me think that the OP *was* about to mix in quite some business logic into the response building code.

Comment: @Dusan: It is perfectly o.k. to disagree. I also wasn't about to answer your question but to raise a point that I think I saw in your question. This is why it was a comment and not an answer. However if you want to contribute to Stackoverflow in a constructive way you may want to reconsider your style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with anonymous types, but if you don't like those, there's a couple of options.

A `Dictionary<string, object>` would behave like your example, and they serialise quite happily. Alternatively, a `dynamic`, which you may have seen in the form of the `ViewBag` object. There's also the [ExpandoObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx?Redirected=true), which is somewhere between the two, behaving like a `dynamic` while using a `Dictionary` under the hood.